# additional scalar summary in Keras

Tags: keras, tensorboard

I am writing a model which optimizing a loss function which consisists of 5 parts

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    ...

    loss = 5. * loss_xy + 5. * loss_wh + loss_conf + 0.5 * loss_notconf + loss_class
    return loss
```

later in the code when I run fit_generator i pass Tensorboard callback and it allows me to see how my loss function behaves. What I can't figure out is how to see individual parts of the final loss function in Tensorboard (loss_xy, loss_w,loss_conf, loss_notconf, loss_class). Is there a proper way to do it? I can't find anything in documentation

```
tensorboard = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, write_graph=True)
tensorboard.set_model(model)

model.fit_generator(generator=train_iterator, epochs=50, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

Comment: For now the only way in Keras to display something with TensorBoard I found is to create additional metric which you pass to `model.compile(metrics=[additional_metric])`

Comment: Have things changed since? This is the only thing I've found after searching for a while. This seems similar / related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515986/getting-a-simple-plot-in-tensorboard but isn't Keras.